# Android Studio: how to show author of just selected line

Tags: android, android-studio, annotations

I noticed a pretty feature in Visual Studio Code (don't know if it's due to the GitLens extension): when I'm editing a line I can see the GIT annotation of that line including author, time of last edit and commit message.

[image]

This is quite cool, since it does not take a big amount of space as the "annotations" pane that you can enable in Android Studio. It's fast, easy, straightforward.

My question is: is there any Android Studio extension, as far as you know, allowing a similar visualization?

Thank you
Marco

Comment: if you saw message it show full name  but in my android studio it only show last name i dont know why any idea how to change it?

Comment: @Adnanhaider I guess it's most probably due to the GIT configuration of the user that pushed the commit

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I managed to get the same in Android studio by using a plugin called GitToolBox

[image]

[image]

Comment: In Mac, go to Android Studio --> Preferences --> Plugins --> Marketplace selector --> find GitToolBox

Comment: This can also be found on Windows by going to File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Searching for GitToolBox and then restarting the IDE

Answer (score 34):

You can right click besides line number (Left side strip where we put breakpoints) in Android studio code and check annotate option.

OR

You can **right click** in code file, then select **Git** option and then select **annotate** option.

Comment: While the option mentioned in this answer is correct, I didn't get the original author of the selected line. To see all the commits modifying the selected line (including original commit which added it) I did this -- select line --> right click --> Git --> show history for selection

Comment: look at [Marco Zanetti answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58392707/9921564), it's worth it ;)

Answer (score 5):

**SOLUTION**

You can try this by right clicking on a place where to add debug break point

[image]

Chill Pill:)